# Task List Can't Send Alerts to User Group

Tags: alert, task-list

I have a Task List I created called Events. When a new task is created I want it to send an Alert to a group called TaskEmailList. This group has Full Control. However, when I create an Alert using the Alert Me button in the Items ribbon on this List I get this message below saying that no results were found when searching for the group TaskEmailList:

[image]

Is it not possible for a Task List to email Alerts to a group? Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

I have found that SP can't send alerts to SP groups by default and that the only way is to create an AD group and add those users to the group. More details can be found [here.](http://www.sharepointviking.com/how-to-send-alerts-to-a-group-in-sharepoint-2010/)